# How to make sure total bytes of a map (sum of all keys and values length) stays within the limit?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am getting lot of records from a particular source and I need to send those records to our database. Below is what I am doing:

- I am storing all these records in a `ConcurrentHashMap` where key is `Integer` and value is `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and this CHM gets populated by multiple threads in a thread safe way.
- Now I have a single background thread (runs every 1 minute) which reads from this map and send those events to some other method which does validation and send it to our database.

Below is my method which will be called by a single background thread every 1 minute.

```
  private void validateAndSend(final int partition,
      final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders) {

    Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
    int totalSize = 0;
    while (!dataHolders.isEmpty()) {
      DataHolder dataHolder = dataHolders.poll();
      byte[] clientKeyBytes = dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      if (clientKeyBytes.length > 255)
        continue;
      byte[] processBytes = dataHolder.getProcessBytes();
      int clientKeyLength = clientKeyBytes.length;
      int processBytesLength = processBytes.length;

      totalSize += clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;
      if (totalSize > 64000) {
        sendToDatabase(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
        clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.clear(); // watch out for gc
        totalSize = 0;
      }
      clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.put(clientKeyBytes, processBytes);
    }
    // calling again with remaining values
    sendToDatabase(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
  }
```

In the above method, I will iterate `dataHolders` CLQ and I will extract `clientKeyBytes` and `processBytes` from it. Here is the validation that I am supposed to do:

- If `clientKeyBytes` length is greater than 255 then I will skip it and continue iterating.
- And then I will keep incrementing `totalSize` variable which will be sum of `clientKeyLength` and `processBytesLength` and this totalSize length should be less than 64000 always.
- As soon as it is reaching `64000` limit, I will send the `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` map to `sendToDatabase` method and clear out the map, reset `totalSize` to 0 and start populating again.
- If it doesn't reaches that limit and `dataHolders` got empty, then we will send whatever we have.

Basically what I have to make sure is whenever `sendToDatabase` method is called, `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` map should have size less than `64000` (sum of all keys and values length). It should never be called with the size greater than `64000`.

Is this the best and efficient way to do what I am doing or there is any better way to accomplish the same thing?

**Update:**

This is how it should be?

```
  private void validateAndSend(final int partition,
      final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders) {

    Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
    int totalSize = 0;
    while (!dataHolders.isEmpty()) {
      DataHolder dataHolder = dataHolders.poll();
      byte[] clientKeyBytes = dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      if (clientKeyBytes.length > 255)
        continue;
      byte[] processBytes = dataHolder.getProcessBytes();
      int clientKeyLength = clientKeyBytes.length;
      int processBytesLength = processBytes.length;

      int additionalLength = clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;
      if (totalSize + additionalLength > 64000) {
        Message message = new Message(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
        sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.getLocation());
        clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.clear(); // watch out for gc
        totalSize = 0;
      }
      clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.put(clientKeyBytes, processBytes);
      totalSize += additionalLength;
    }
    // calling again with remaining values
    Message message = new Message(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
    sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.getLocation());
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you might want a Guava `Cache` with a `maxWeight` and a `Weigher`.  But you can't query the current weight nor recognize when it's approaching the maximum size.  The concurrency makes this hard.

Comment: I am ok doing this manually in the code itself by calculating the size and as soon as it is reaching the limit sending it over. So what I have right now is good or any better way to rewrite the same thing?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You should decouple the in-memory data structure from filling up the sending buffer.  If you counted  key _characters_, then `getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` could return more bytes than you allowed for.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am happy to improve my question if there is anything missing. What do you want me to decouple in my answer? And I didn't understand your more bytes question. Can you elaborate on that as well?

Comment: If you counted 100 _characters_ and one of those characters is not ASCII (i.e. an accented letter or greek letter, for instance), then the conversion to UTF-8 bytes will return more than 100 _bytes_ (i.e. 101, 102 or 103 depending on the particular character).  I would feed `DataHolder` objects one at a time to a class that serializes them and fills a `byte[]` buffer.  When the current buffer length + the serialized length of the current object exceeds the limit, send the buffer, clear it and place the object in the buffer.  That way you're counting the right length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, but there is a small bug: `totalSize` is reset to 0 where it should be set to `clientKeyLength + processBytesLength` -- the bytes for the current key are ignored when the data is sent, although the entry is added after the if statement.

I'd change the code as follows (the whole question might be better suited for the codereviews stack exchange):

```
int additionalLength = clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;
if (totalSize + additionalLength > 64000) {
    sendToDatabase(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
    clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.clear(); // watch out for gc
    totalSize = 0;
}
clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.put(clientKeyBytes, processBytes);
totalSize += additionalLength;
```

P.S.: What is the expected behavior when the same key is inserted multiple times? Your code currently inserts all instances...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that bug. `dataHolder.getClientKey()` will always be unique as it has current timestamp in it so that means `clientKeyBytes` will also be unique.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. wanted to make sure, this is what you meant? And also in the if block `if (totalSize + additionalLength > 64000) {` why we need `additionalLength` check? It should already be added right for that check with my previous line?

Comment: The line `totalSize += clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;` needs to be removed, otherwise you'll add the amount twice. A single line fix (compared to your original code) would be to change `totalSize = 0` to `totalSize = clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;`

Comment: I see what you mean. You did it slightly different than what I was doing. I thought you corrected the bug in my original code itself. Updated the question with the correct code again. Let me know if this time I got it right?

Comment: Yes, now it looks good in the "is this how it should be" section

Comment: quick question, is there any way by which I can call `sendToDatabase` method only once by rewriting it in a better way? Because right now, I am calling `sendToDatabase` method at two places one is as soon as it is reaching 64k limit and other is it didn't reach bcoz we ran out of elements.

Comment: You could add `|| dataHolder.isEmpty()` to the condition for sending

Comment: Where should I add this condition? If possible can you edit with this so that I can understand on how can I call `sendToDatabase` method only once?

Comment: Change the existing condition `if (totalSize + additionalLength > 64000)` to `if (totalSize + additionalLength > 64000 ||  dataHolder.isEmpty()` and remove sendToDatabase at the end